# JQuery change() function is not working when there is only one option in select list

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get data using jquery from a select list which is populated dynamically. Jquery change() functions works well when there are many options in the list but it doesn't fire when there is only one option. My code is below

```
<?php
    $res=$db->SelectData("amgusers");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {    
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
            echo'<option value="'.$row['u_id'].'">'.$row['u_username'].'</option>';
        }
    }                           
?>

<script>    
    $("#uname").change(function()
    {
        alert($("#uname option:selected").text());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please show full html please

Comment: if there is only one option, how does it change and why would you need to fire an event?  If you definitely need it, then put a default please select option at the top (but then this may mean you need to validate something has been chosen) - that way you will always have at least 2 options

Comment: You can probably do   `$("#uname").change(function()
    {
        alert($("#uname option:selected").text());
    }).trigger('change');` if you want to force it.

Comment: You can add a `option` "Select Value" before the dynamically populated options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.  Add more events or set a default and trigger it. OR combine that. You might also set the default to the first either in markup (selected) or force ONLY if one.

Two events (seems to not be great if you only have one, or do not change it)

```js
$("#uname").on('change click', function() {
  if ($(this).find('option').length === 1 && !$(this).find('option:selected').length) {
    $(this).find('option').prop("selected", true);
  }
  alert($(this).find("option:selected").text() + " : " + $(this).val());
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="uname">
  <option value="me">My Option</option>
</select>
```

Better perhaps, I find the multiple events is probably NOT great since you only want it on a change SO I opt for that. (and "click" just seems to not be suitable here)

```js
$("#uname").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).find('option').length === 1 && !$(this).find('option:selected').length) {
    $(this).find('option').prop("selected", true);
  }
  alert($(this).find("option:selected").text() + " : " + $(this).val());
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="uname">
  <option value="me">My Option</option>
</select>
```

Note this second set of code also works when you have an "empty" first option value but you might then also need to make the first one NOT select-able or otherwise handle that condition when it is selected.

Comment: with more than one option the event will fire twice

Comment: @aje - yes, I added the option to NOT use a click also since it seems the cleaner approach.  I never like click events unless there is a specific reason on inputs including selects, radio buttons etc.

Comment: @aje - the reason the first one fires twice is that there are two events attached (click and change) and you would need to handle that, perhaps with a `e.preventPropagation` or some such to keep the "next" one from firing.

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one item in the dropdown, it wont work.

You can try `onClick()` instead.

Otherwise make an option as `--select--` on the top of select box. Ignore that accordingly in your JavaScript.